# Analogy in combination of batteries in series and pn junction diode circuit to find potential difference

Tags: semiconductors

Can I use the analogy of combination of two batteries to get the potential difference between two points in case a pn junction diode is used in the case of other battery? In doing so what is the basic mistake in doing that ? I think about this a lot but could not get.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Kirchoffs loop law applies, subtract the 0.6V from the PN junction from the 2V battery ad you'll get 1.4V between A and B

Comment: Then why in combination of batteries we add up the voltages?

Comment: you only add batteries if the potential difference faces the same direction.

Comment: In a similar manner the potential in the barrier should also be added

Comment: it can only be added if it's aiding.

Comment: In both the cases they will tend to change the direction of previous battery

Comment: A silicon diode with forward bias is typically a 0.6 to 1V voltage drop.  reverse biased it will usually block all the current.

Comment: In forward bias if I assume barrier potential a battery of barrier potential voltage then it would be like combining two batteries and their potential will add up

Answer (score 0):

As long as the loop is open (A nd B NOT connected) the value and the polarity of the battery will have no influence on the diffusion voltage across the pn junction (app 0.6V). That means: You can (theoretically !) calculate the sum or difference between both voltages, depending on the polarities. But it will not be possible to measure the resulting voltage (even in case of an IDEAL volt meter with an infinite input resistance).

Comment: Using Kirchhoff's law should I add or subtract the of barrier potential in forward bias? The field is directed from n to p side so theoretically I need to subtract

Comment: As long as A and B are not connected, the pn junction is NOT biased at all!

Comment: Okay what will be the case when connected?

Comment: Whe connected and forward biased (with an external voltage below - let`s say - 0.8 V) , the internal diffusion voltage will be reduced, the depletion zone gets smaller and a current will exist.