# Does input signal mean same as input in transistors as amplifier?

Tags: voltage, transistors, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, semiconductors

During solving [[this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbDLP.jpg)] I came across a term **input signal**, I want to know whether input signal means the **input voltage or change in input voltage**? I am unable to solve if I take input signal as change in input voltage, because i don't know the change in output voltage.

Also if I take input signal as input voltage and output signal as output voltage then also iam unable to solve since I don't know the output voltage , only the voltage across output resistance is given and we know that \$\ V_output = V_cc - I_c R_c\$ (where \$\ V_cc\$ is collector voltage in ce configuration) to find output  I know only\$\ I_c R_c\$ but not \$\ V_cc\$

If go with assumption 1 then I am getting input signal (ie. change) but how to find the base current ( as given in question only base current not the base signal current) because the only relation know is \$\ dV_i = R_b dI_b + dV_be\$. If \$\ dV_be\$ is assumed very small and then neglecting it  \$\ dV_i = R_b dI_b\$ so on substitution I would get the change in base current but not the base current. So what is the way to find the base current (not the base current signal)?

Please clarify and also help by providing any link to an integrated glossary of electrnics.

**ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED**

Comment: Please first define the term input signal

Comment: This is pretty basic.  Seriously.  An "input signal", whether digital or analog, or whatever else you might want, is the input to a circuit.  That's it.  Likewise, the output signal is, well, the output from a circuit.  The in-between circuit elements don't matter in the slightest.

Comment: @RDrast         Please check the edited  second part , I f I take signal as change then I am unable to find out the base current. Sorry for such basics but I am new to this because I am just a class 12 student  and novice in this field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JM97 - as you probably know, each transistor-based signal amplifier needs DC biasing. Hence, we always have to discriminate between (a) DC currents and voltages and (b) signal currents and voltages. That means: Varying currents/voltages around such a bias point (quiescent point) is considered to be a "signal".

Example: IC and VCE are DC values defining the operational DC point and corresponding changes (d(IC) and d(VCE), respectively) are signals. In many cases these deviations from the DC values are time varying in form of sinusoidal waves.

As far as your task is concerned, I am sure that SIGNAL quantities (voltages and currents) are in question (even if they speak about "base current" only without saying explicitely "signal base current"). So, in principle, you have nothing to do than to apply Ohms law for relating voltages and currents and vice versa (the corresponding resistors are given).

Comment: Could you answer this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209174/analogy-in-combination-of-batteries-in-series-and-pn-junction-diode-circuit-to-f.

Comment: I gave an answer just now.